# How to render non-model objects in django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have the following model listed in Django admin already with the following view:

```
class BookTabularInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Book

@register(Bookcase)
class BookcaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [BookTabularInline]
```

The changes I want to make is:

1. Instead of returning all the Books associated with Bookcase, I only want to return specific ones via queryset for example: `Books.objects.filter(isAvailable=True, bookcase=bookcase).order_by("name")`. How can I accomplish this?
2. Instead of returning the model (Book) from this queryset, I want to return a BookPublicObject with different attributes inline, but BookPublicObject is a dataclass and not a Django model. Is this possible?

Comment: For #1, you can [override get_queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) and add your filter there.

Comment: @BrianDestura Thanks! I can only return a query set though. If I want to do more processing of the data AFTER the query has ran is that possible?

Comment: That might be better done on the view instead. Since `get_queryset` by the name returns a queryset and not a dataclass or something else. Are you able to share more details?